# Rails has_secure_password on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm writing my own user auth system in Rails and I am trying to simplify the registration process. I only want new users to provide an email on registration and then a password will be emailed to them but using `has_secure_password` I'm getting told that **password can't be blank**.

I would like to create a random password on signup that will be emailed to them so that they can access their account in the future but how can I "inject" this password before the validations take place.

I guess the place to do it is in a `before_create` in the user model but any advice/code samples on this would be much appreciated.

At the moment I have this but still getting **password can't be blank** message.

```
#user.rb
has_secure_password

before_create :set_temporary_password

def set_temporary_password
  self.password = SecureRandom.hex(5)
  self.password_confirmation = self.password
  #email the password or better still, a link to create a password
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to `before_validation` should work, check callback lifecycle here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html